# How do i include only the jars from my dependency tags

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I have created a maven jar with dependencies for my spark project and when I see the size of that dependencies jar , it is 112 MB and that too big , As the size is too big i am not  able to place
that dependencies jar inside edge node because of quoto issue

How do i get a jar that contains the code that i have written inside /src/main/scala and also i need the jars inide

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.corp</groupId>
  <artifactId>Corp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
 <properties>
 <scala.version>2.12.6</scala.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
<repository>
  <id>scala-tools.org</id>
  <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
  <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
</repository>
</repositories>

 <pluginRepositories>
 <pluginRepository>
  <id>scala-tools.org</id>
  <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
  <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
 </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>${scala.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
  <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
  <artifactId>config</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>

    <build>
   <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
   <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
      <args>
        <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
      </args>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
      <buildcommands>
        <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
      </buildcommands>
      <additionalProjectnatures>
        <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
      </additionalProjectnatures>
      <classpathContainers>
        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
        <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
      </classpathContainers>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
 </build>
 <reporting>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you. You say that the JAR with all the dependencies is too large, but what do you want instead? You say you "need the jars inside", but isn't that the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit your job to the Spark runtime, the Spark jars are already available within the runtime, so you do not need to include them in your jar.

You can set the scope of the `scala-library`, `spark-core_2.11` and `spark-sql_2.11` (and any other Spark dependency that you might add in future) to [provided](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). The [assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) will skip these libraries (as well as all of their transitive dependencies), thus reducing the size of your jar. As these jars are already part of your Spark runtime, your Spark job will still work. You should only include libraries in your jar that are not part of Spark, like the `com.typesafe:config` library.